# Let $f(x) = x^3 -x^2 -13x+24$. Find all pairs $(x,y)$ such that if $y=f(x)$, then $x=f(y)$.

Tags: polynomials

I know how to do this with integer roots in that to ensure that both equations $y = f(x)$ and $x = f(y)$ are satisfied is to have $y = x$.

The equation $f(x) = x$ becomes $x^3 - x^2 - 13x + 24 = x$, which simplifies as $x^3 - x^2 - 14x + 24 = 0$. If there are any integer roots, then they must be among the factors of 24. Checking these values, we find that the cubic becomes $0$ for $x = 2, 3, and -4$. This gives us the three solutions $\boxed{(2,2)\text{,}(3,3)\text{, and }(-4,-4)}$

Now I don't know how I would go about finding all such solutions.

Comment: "*I know how to do this with integer roots*" $\;-\;$ That's not guaranteed to find *all* integer solutions, either.

Comment: @dxiv Shouldn't the solutions lie on the line $y=x$? Therefore those are the only three solutions, right ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Learningstill No, they need not. All that the symmetry implies is that if $(x,y)$ is a solution then $(y,x)$ is also a solution. It does *not* imply that $x=y$.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your question in the body, not only (and not necessarily) in the title. And please clarify your post: your question in the title is: find the fixed points of $f\circ f$ whereas in the body you seem interested in the fixed points of $f.$

Answer (score 2):

Even if $x$ and $y$ are restricted to integers, the simultaneous conditions $$y = f(x), \quad x = f(y) \tag{1}$$ do not require that $y = x$.  For example, if $f(x) = 1 - x$, then $(x,y) = (0,1)$ is a solution.  In fact, $$f(f(x)) = 1 - (1 - x) = x,$$ so for this choice of $f$, *every* ordered pair satisfying $y = 1-x$ will satisfy $(1)$.

With this in mind, we might get an idea of how to proceed when $$f(x) = x^3 - x^2 - 13x + 24. \tag{2}$$  Clearly, if $f(x) = y$ and $f(y) = x$, then $f(f(x)) = f(y) = x$.  So we would want to solve
$$f(f(x)) - x = 0. \tag{3}$$  Unfortunately, this is a degree-$9$ polynomial in $x$ with rather large coefficients.  So we exploit the fact that if $y = x$, then we also have solutions, and these will necessarily be factors of $(3)$.  As you have already obtained via the rational root theorem or trial factorization, $$g(x) = f(x) - x = (x+4)(x-2)(x-3), \tag{4}$$ which furnishes the solutions $(x,y) \in (-4,-4), (2,2), (3,3)$.  Consequently,
$$\begin{align}
0 &= f(f(x)) - x \\
&= \bigl(f(f(x)) - f(x)\bigr) + \bigl(f(x) - x\bigr)\\
&= g(f(x)) + g(x) \\
&= g(f(x) - x + x) + g(x) \\
&= g(g(x) + x) + g(x) \\
&= \bigl(g(x)+x+4\bigr)\bigl(g(x)+x-2\bigr)\bigl(g(x)+x-3\bigr) + g(x) \\
&= g(x) \bigl((x-3)(x-2)+1\bigr)\bigl((x+4)(x-3)+1\bigr)\bigl((x+4)(x-2)+1\bigr) + g(x) \\
&= g(x) \bigl((x^2-5x+7)(x^2+x-11)(x^2+2x-7) + 1\bigr) \\
\tag{5}
\end{align}$$
However, the nontrivial factor $$h(x) = (x^2-5x+7)(x^2+x-11)(x^2+2x-7) + 1 \tag{6}$$ in $(5)$ has roots that do not appear to be expressible by radicals.  Numerically, they are approximately

$$x \in \{1.85488,2.82787,-3.84147 \pm 0.0218677 i, 2.5001 \pm 0.851815 i\}.$$

Comment: An even better first example could be $f(x)=x^2-1$. There are $4$ solutions to $f(x)=y, f(y)=x$, out of which $2$ are integer solutions $(0,-1)$ and $(-1,0)$ but neither of those satisfies $y=x$.

Answer (score -1):

Define $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 - 13 x + 24$.

Then solve:  $x= f(x^3 - x^2 - 13 x + 24)$

$\left\{\{x\to -4\},\{x\to 2\},\{x\to 3\},\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6-2
   \text{$\#$1}^5-24 \text{$\#$1}^4+72 \text{$\#$1}^3+110 \text{$\#$1}^2-588
   \text{$\#$1}+540\&,1\right]\right\},\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6-2
   \text{$\#$1}^5-24 \text{$\#$1}^4+72 \text{$\#$1}^3+110 \text{$\#$1}^2-588
   \text{$\#$1}+540\&,2\right]\right\},\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6-2
   \text{$\#$1}^5-24 \text{$\#$1}^4+72 \text{$\#$1}^3+110 \text{$\#$1}^2-588
   \text{$\#$1}+540\&,3\right]\right\},\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6-2
   \text{$\#$1}^5-24 \text{$\#$1}^4+72 \text{$\#$1}^3+110 \text{$\#$1}^2-588
   \text{$\#$1}+540\&,4\right]\right\},\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6-2
   \text{$\#$1}^5-24 \text{$\#$1}^4+72 \text{$\#$1}^3+110 \text{$\#$1}^2-588
   \text{$\#$1}+540\&,5\right]\right\},\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6-2
   \text{$\#$1}^5-24 \text{$\#$1}^4+72 \text{$\#$1}^3+110 \text{$\#$1}^2-588
   \text{$\#$1}+540\&,6\right]\right\}\right\}$